# Chinese characters signature? Yixing (Characters identified: 吴亮屏)

Tags: character-identification

What are the symbols on this very old teapot? It appears to be traditional chinese characters or a date?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's 吴亮屏.

if you do a search online, this is kinda famous kind of 紫砂壶 [click](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%90%B4%E4%BA%AE%E5%B1%8F%20%E7%B4%AB%E7%A0%82&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS850US850&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=fdF4QN-pP8Lk-M%253A%252C_9659CHhLfxLNM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRX5XU1bNI_wS5yarBv3KY98Wkksw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiThObbmo7nAhXQtlkKHT5uDgwQ9QEwAXoECAoQBw#imgrc=xbDXqFbssYf0cM:&vet=1)

however, the stamp looks different from what I see online, so not sure if it's real.